# Jquery clone() doesn't clone new value set wit data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jquery data() to set data attribute of an element, like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="some-el" data-number="0"></div>
```

JQ:

```
$("#some-el").data("number",1);
```

As we know, data changes variable internally. So inside inspector you cannot actually see that new value is 1. But this aside, if I do clone on the element with new data value, jquery clones original dom element without current data value!!!

```
$("#some-el").clone();
```

Results in `<div id="some-el" data-number="0"></div>` both internally and visibly!

I was thinking I could avoid this problem by simply using `attr("data-number",1);`

Anyways, I wanted to ask you if this is correct behaviour of dat()? Is what I'm seeing expected? and WHY?

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: All is explain here: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think clone can accept a boolean to indicate a Clone with data and events, so `Clone(true)` should work: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Here's a fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/2pdNL/

Comment: I guess OP is referring [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/J76vp.jpg) behavior.  It is not shown in the dev tools.

Comment: This will make life easier, didn't want to rewrite my js :) thanks!

Comment: Clone(true) didn't work with jquery-ui sortable! so I had to go with attr way.

Answer (score 5):

`.data()` is not setting the value in DOM.

> The `data-` attributes are pulled in the **first time** the data property is
>   accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values
>   are then stored internally in jQuery)

But here is a workaround, instead of using

```
$("#some-el").data("number",1);
```

Interact directly to DOM like

```
$("#some-el").attr("data-number",1);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/qYX7f/4/)

Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708345/1671639)

Comment: What did you say that I didn't have in my question? :)

Comment: Also note, that if you want to set js object as value for the "data-number" (in this case) attribute, you have to stringify it.