# Change data-depth attribute of a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the data-depth of a div with a new class but it won't change
really need help here, would appreciate if someone could help

here is my code

```
$('div.new').data('depth') === 1.00;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use the comparison operator to set the value, which won't work.

In addition, `$('div.new').data('depth')` retrieves the `data-depth` attribute value, you can't actually set it even if you use the `=` operator.

Depending on your jQuery version, you could use `$('div.new').data('data-depth', 1.00)` to set the value. However, it is probably safer to use the [`.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), since the `.data()` method [won't always work when setting a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attrdata-itemname-does).

```
$('div.new').attr('data-depth', 1.00);
```