# How to set both $.data('value') and $.attr('data-value')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a lack of vocabulary there.

I'm trying to understand the difference between `$.data('value')` and `$.attr('data-value')`

Of what I'm understanding, the both are set up on load as long as there is the attribute `data-value="kitty"` on the html tag.

However when I'm trying to interract with them they are independent

[image]

So first of all I'd like to understand what is happening there :/.

And secondly is there a way to interact with both at the same time?

[JsFiddle for test](https://jsfiddle.net/t580xzj3/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does

Comment: It's the same method. But when you're doing `$('div').attr('data-value', 'oloy')` - it's return you the jQuery object