# data attribute not updated before page refresh with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

In my project I have a table, each of its rows holding id and title as data attributes

```
<tr data-id="1" data-title="title"><td id="td_title">some text</td></tr>
```

I use jQuery to update the data-tile attribute

```
$newTitle = 'newTitle';
$row_to_update = $("tr").find("[data-id='1']");
$row_to_update.attr('data-title', newTitle );
```

So after that, in  the html I can see the updated values, but if I try this:

```
$var = $row_to_update.data('title');
alert($var);
```

It returns the old title, unless I load the page again.
I suppose I have to clear the cache, but I only found `$.domCache`, which is not applicable to jQuery and also saw and tried

```
function clearjQueryCache(){
    for (var x in jQuery.cache){
        delete jQuery.cache[x];
    }
}
```

but obviously not correct, as everything stopped working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method allows us to search through the descendants of these
>   elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the
>   matching elements. The .find() and .children() methods are similar,
>   except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

ًWith `$("tr").find("[data-id='1']");` `tr` doesn't have  element with `[data-id='1']` to find it .. So no need to use `.find()`

```
$newTitle = 'newTitle';
$row_to_update = $("tr[data-id='1']");
$row_to_update.data('title', $newTitle );
//then
$var = $row_to_update.data('title');
alert($var);  // the output should be newTitle
```

Working demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $newTitle = 'newTitle';
  $row_to_update = $("tr[data-id='1']");
  $row_to_update.data('title', $newTitle );
  //then
  $var = $row_to_update.data('title');
  alert($var);  // the output should be newTitle
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr data-id="1" data-title="title"><td id="td_title">some text</td></tr>
<tr data-id="2" data-title="title"><td id="td_title">some text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, although I can clearly see your code is working, even if I use  $("tr[data-id='1']") for me the alert() still shows the old value.

Comment: @Dimentica did you change `.attr('data-title', newTitle );`  with `.attr('data-title', $newTitle );` .. And CTRL+F5 will refresh your website

Comment: Yes, I did, I can see in the html the title is changed, but the alert message thinks else

Comment: @Dimentica if you can see the `data-title` updated .. you should get the alert .. Please keep eyes on console for errors

Comment: So! I changed it not to $row_to_update.attr('data-title', $newTitle ); but to $row_to_update.data('title', $newTitle ); it is ok now. Thank you!

Comment: @Dimentica both should work as it shown on a demo .. but anyway if `data()` works for you its ok .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: I really do not know why the one works and the other does, still, you were of great help! Have a nice day too :)

Comment: @Dimentica can you please return the code back and instead of `$var = $row_to_update.data('title');` use `$var = $row_to_update.attr('data-title');` and let me know what you'll get .. Actually [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708345/3385827) let me thinking about *don't intermix .data and .attr() calls. Use one or the other.*

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `.data('title')`, you can use `.attr('data-title')`. This may work.