# How to load file based on data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to load a file based on data attribute?

For some reason $(this) does not seems to work.

```js
if ($('.html').data('load-file')) {
  $(this).load($(this).data("load-file") + ' ' +   $(this).data("load-content"));
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.html {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div 
  class="html" 
  data-load-file="../index.html" 
  data-load-content=".icon_environment"></div>

<div class="html"></div>
```

Comment: `this` where that code is is referring to the global object (window, in this case). Did you intend it to refer to something else?

Comment: No… it needs to load in the div within itself

Comment: then apply the data attributes accordingly

Comment: Unrelated typo: `cal(100% - 10px)` should be `calc(100% - 10px)`.

Comment: Another typo? `.icon_enviroment` => `.icon_environment` (note the `n`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in that code is the window (the global object). I think you probably meant for it to refer to the element that has the `data-*` attributes on it.

You probably want to handle those elements individually, so your best bet is to find them and loop through them with `each`, which will let you target them individually and will call your callback with `this` referring to each one:

```
$('.html[data-load-file][data-load-content]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.load($this.attr("data-load-file") + ' ' + $this.attr("data-load-content"));
});
```

or:

```
$('.html[data-load-file][data-load-content]').each(function() {
  $(this).load(this.getAttribute("data-load-file") + ' ' + this.getAttribute("data-load-content"));
});
```

That finds all elements with the class `html` and also the two `data-*` attributes we require, loops through them individually, and uses their attributes to call `load`.

**Live on plunkr**: http://plnkr.co/edit/lzHBYxVSETvHzTt6l2KR?p=preview

---

Side note: I switched the above to using `attr` rather than `data`, because there wasn't any indication you're using the features `data` provides. Remember that `data` is **not** an accessor for `data-*` attributes. It's both more and less than that. [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219).

Comment: I didn't do a Stack Snippet because they're for **live** examples, and we can't make this example live since it requires external resources (the pages to load).

Comment: I tried the code… but it does not work for some reason

Comment: @MonwellPartee: You'll hae to debug it. Fundamnetally, that *will* call `load` with the attributes in question.

Comment: @MonwellPartee: Just tried it locally. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @MonwellPartee: Works on plunkr, too: http://plnkr.co/edit/lzHBYxVSETvHzTt6l2KR?p=preview

Comment: I copied word for word… and you get the badge of honor my good fellow

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery(this) does not refer to your div.html, it refer to the whole document.

You need to replace jQuery(this) by jQuery('.html'), or to get each div.html and make an enclosure to be sure jQuery(this) refer to your div.html.

Also add a document ready to be sure it's not executed before page load when you don't have div.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('.html[data-load-file]').each(function(){
    
    var loadFile = jQuery(this).data('load-file') ;
    console.log(loadFile) ;
    var loadContent = jQuery(this).data('load-content') ;
    console.log(loadContent) ;
  
    var load_url = loadFile + ' ' + loadContent ;
    console.log(load_url) ;
  
    jQuery(this).load(load_url);
    
  }) ;
    
}) ;
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.html {
width: calc(100% - 10px);
height: 80px;
margin: 10px;
background: #f6f6f6;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div 
  class="html" 
  data-load-file="../index.html" 
  data-load-content=".icon_environment"></div>

<div class="html"></div>
```

Comment: I've edited so you can see what appens. You try to do : `jQuery('.html').load('../index.html .icon_enviroment')` : i don't know what you want to do in the end but i guess you want to take the content of .icon_enviroment from your index. 1) are your sure your index is in a parent dir ? 2) are your sure it's enviroment and not environment ?

Comment: It retrieves the div with the class icon_environment from the html

Comment: I've edited snippet to make environment and not enviroment.