# Set data attribute via object initializer in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set the data attribute for a tag (like *data-id*="..") using the following way:

`$('<p>', {text: 'bla', data-?: '..'}).appendTo('#tagToAppendTo');`

Unfortunetaly, I am not able to define the custom part (here marked as ?) in the object. Is there a way to do it like this, or do I need to resort to the *.data()* function?

Comment: $('<p>', {text: 'bla', 'data-test': 'some value'}).appendTo('#tagToAppendTo');?! Is that your issue?

Comment: I will try it again, i got an error doing it in this way.
Update: I am dumb, i tried to set it without quotes. It makes sense that a custom attribute needs to be put in quotes.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: But imho @Etibu, it is not really clear what you are asking here?! Especially because you are talking about `.data()` which isn't used for setting `data-*` attribute

Comment: Just FYI, JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. *(Sorry, meant to post this earlier.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the propety name in quotes when it's not a valid identifier name:

```
$('<p>', {text: 'bla', 'data-id': '..'}).appendTo('#tagToAppendTo');
// --------------------^-------^
```

Either single or double quotes are fine.

> Is there a way to do it like this, or do I need to resort to the .data() function?

[`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) doesn't set attributes. Details: [jQuery .data() does not work, but .attr() does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219)

Comment: Expanding your answer - if you use special chars as key of json, you have to use single or double quotes.

Comment: @Sylwek This has nothing to do with `json`, it is javascript object. JSON is just a notation and only double quotes is valid regarding JSON notation

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, you're right. I wrote it in wrong words

Comment: @Sylwek I guess you get fooled by question's title :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `.attr` option to set custom `data-*` values.

Snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('<p>', {text: 'bla'}).attr('data-test','sample-value').appendTo('#tagToAppendTo');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tagToAppendTo"></div>
```