# jQuery $('body').on with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I have function

```
    $('body').on('click', '.urlsend', function ()
    {
         console.log("this.parameter");
    }
```

and all elements with ".urlsend" have some parameter, which I need to pass to the function. 
HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="canvas">

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadImgs(){

<!--somecode-->

  function gotData(arr){
    var element="";
    for(var i = 0;i<arr.data.length;i++)
    {
        var img = arr.data[i].images.original.url;
        element += '<img src="'+img+'" class="urlsend" data-url="'+img+'">';

    }
    $('#canvas').html(element);
  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.attr` to get parameter or attribute of an HTML element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.urlsend', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("parameter"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="urlsend" parameter="1"> urlsend DIV 1</div>
<div class="urlsend" parameter="2"> urlsend DIV 2</div>
<div class="urlsend" parameter="3"> urlsend DIV 3</div>
<div class="urlsend" parameter="4"> urlsend DIV 4</div>
```

Doc: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: You have to change the `$(this).attr("parameter")` parameter name. On my example, it is called `parameter`

Comment: Because I used `<div class="urlsend" parameter="1">` parameter as my attribute name on my html code.

Comment: Yes, I know. I need to send img src, so I used attr('src') and also tried your method. None worked

Comment: Does img has class urlsend?

Comment: Well, problem is, that there are no IMGS. They are dynamicly created. I mean you type keyword to searchbox and multiple images appear.

Comment: Then just copy several images from developer tools. Or take a screenshot of the img html on dev tools

Comment: Well, this should work `console.log($(this).attr("src"));`

Comment: When you `console.log( this );` What are you getting?

Comment: https://ctrlv.cz/gEyt
Now I see, that problem is in WS I am using, that $(this) is not relevant to this in specific function, but to whole app variable in websocket.

Comment: Yeah. the `this` should be the image you are trying to get the attribute

Comment: I tried to log e.target (and passing e in function) and it works. Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Yeah! I am about to tell you about the event target.

Answer (score 0):

`this` within the callback will be the specific `.urlsend` element that the event relates to, so you can access the information from `this`.

For instance, if the "parameter" is a `data-info` attribute:

```
console.log(this.getAttribute("data-info"));
```

or with more jQuery:

```
console.log($(this).attr("data-info"));
```

(Don't use `.data(...)` unless you want the features it provides, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219) for details.)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <script>
     $(function(){
       $('body').on('click' , ' .urlsend' , function(){
    var url=$(this).data('url');
   var user=$(this).data('user');
alert(url);
alert(user);
  });
  });
</script>    

<body>
<button class="urlsend" data-url="google.com" data-user="kate">click</button>
</body>
```

hope this help you