# Targeting a sister/brother element with the same data-id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hopefully this one doesn't go off the beaten track too much - but I was wondering what the quickest method is in jQuery for targeting another element (that is a close relative of `$(this).whatever`) with the same data id attribute. I currently have the following markup (if you use the latest Bootstrap you'll notice that this is just a simple card with nav headings):

```
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header pb-0">
    <ul id="contactGroups" class="nav justify-content-center nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item" data-id="1">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-id="2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business Enquiries</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-id="3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Follow Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body active" data-id="1">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body hidden" data-id="2">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body hidden" data-id="3">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the above markup I have data-id attributes added to the list elements - I want to then go in and find it's corresponding data-id (the ones with the card-body active or card-body hidden) so I can begin to play with them. However (!!) I don't want to select on some arbitary #id or .class that I assign. How would I go about doing this?

My jQuery thus far is as follows (however, this only flips the current class from non-active (or no class) to the active class giving the tab swop illusion:

```
$('#contactGroups').each(function(){
  $(this).find('li').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function() {                
      $('#contactGroups').find('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
    })
  });
});
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at siblings() in the jQuery documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite make out whether you

1. Want to find the `div` with the same `data-id` as the `li`, or
2. Want to find other `li`s that are siblings ("brothers" + "sisters" = "siblings") of the `li` that was clicked which also have `data-id` attributes.

In the click handler on the `li`, `this` will refer to the `li` that was clicked (it or its descendant `a` element). With that in mind:

#### Assuming #1:

You can get the `data-id` of that element using [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
var theId = `$(this).attr("data-id");
```

(Don't use `data("id")` unless you need the features `data` provides; [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219).)

You can find elements within a given container using `find`, or siblings via `siblings`. So starting from the clicked `li`, you can either do `.closest(".card-header").siblings(...)` to access the header's siblings, or `.closest(".card").find(...)` to search all through the containing `.card`. The former is more specific, but more fragile; the latter is more robust if your structure changes a bit. Neither matters in terms of performance.

So I'd probably go up to `.card` and use `find` with a tag and attribute selector combination:

```
$(this).closest(".card").find("div[data-id='" + theId + "']")...
```

FWIW, there's no need to hook `click` on each individual `li`. Just use event delegation:

```
$("#contactGroups").on("click", "li[data-id]", function() {
    var theId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var div = $(this).closest(".card").find("div[data-id='" + theId + "']");
    // ...
});
```

#### Assuming #2

Use `$(this).siblings("[data-id]")` in the `li` click handler to find all of its siblings with a `data-id` (with any value).

---

### Full Working Example

...based on your comments:

```js
$("#contactGroups").on("click", "li[data-id]", function() {
    var theId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var div = $(this).closest(".card").find("div[data-id='" + theId + "']");
    div.removeClass("hidden").addClass("active");
    div.siblings("[data-id]").removeClass("active").addClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header pb-0">
    <ul id="contactGroups" class="nav justify-content-center nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item" data-id="1">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-id="2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business Enquiries</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-id="3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Follow Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body active" data-id="1">
    <h5 class="card-title">(1) Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body hidden" data-id="2">
    <h5 class="card-title">(2) Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body hidden" data-id="3">
    <h5 class="card-title">(3) Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi T.J, many thanks for this answer - I just want to clarify something which might not have been made obvious by my original question. If you look up the tree you'll see .card-body .active classes with the corresponding IDs...they're not inside the `#contactgroups` div...

Comment: P.S. I'd give you a +100 for the FWIW pro-tip - that worked a charm.

Comment: I think I have worked with what you've got - I changed the ID selector. However, I'm also looking for all divs with a data ID in that DOM to be able to "hide" them simultaneously.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts: Updated. No need for any IDs. :-)

Comment: I like it! Now, I used your question to do the following: `div.addClass('active').removeClass('hidden');` - but I also need to do the inverse on all the other divs where the data id does not match ... i.e., `removeClass('active').addClass('hidden');`

Comment: I'll accept as correct, as it is. I may ask my above comment as a separate question if needed.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts: Just use `.siblings("[data-id]").removeClass("hidden").addClass("active")` on the one that matched. :-)

Comment: Absolutely perfect, and with 4 lines of code. I added two - but 6 in total! I trust this is a very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need an `each` because you have only one `contactGroups`.
- Use the `data` function from jQuery.
- With `closest` function you can get the ancestor of `li` elements.
- Use `toggleClass` function to add or remove the class `active`.
- Use this selector `$('div[data-id="${id}"]')` to find the related `li`'s `div`.
- You can use this selector to bind the click event `$('#contactGroups li').on('click'), ...);`

```js
$('#contactGroups li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('#contactGroups').find('.active').toggleClass('active');

  $(this).children('a').toggleClass('active');

  $('div.card-body.active').toggleClass('active');

  let id = $(this).data('id');
  $(`div[data-id="${id}"]`).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green !important;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header pb-0">
    <ul id="contactGroups" class="nav justify-content-center nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item" data-id="1">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-id="2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business Enquiries</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-id="3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Follow Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body active" data-id="1">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body hidden" data-id="2">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body hidden" data-id="3">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant - worked perfectly. ++ for using let instead of var as well! ;)