# Cannot get autocomplete field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have autocomplete field

```js
$('.airport_field_destination').on('autocompleteselect', (event, ui) => {
  var id = Number($(this).attr('data-number'))

  $(`#search_legs_${id + 1}_origin_text`).val(ui.item.value);
  $(`#search_legs_${id + 1}_origin_id`).val(ui.item.id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search[legs][0][destination_text]" id="search_legs_0_destination_text" value="London (LON), England" class="field-3 airport_field airport_field_destination ui-autocomplete-input" data-number="0" placeholder="Till" data-source="/autocomplete/destination/flight"
  data-id-element="#search_legs_0_destination_id" autocomplete="off">
```

But `var id` says NaN to me

Where is my trouble?

**UPDATE**

With `event.target` I'm able to get id. But `ui.item.value` show me undefined

Comment: Does it work if you try using `.data('number')` instead of `.attr('data-number')`? I have the feeling [`attr()` may not work with `data-*` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))

Comment: have you tried `$(this).data('number')` ?

Comment: Yes, still same thing@Niladri

Comment: Still same thing@JonathanLam

Comment: Can you log `$(this).attr('data-number')` and tell me what you get?

Comment: try `console.log($(event.target).attr('data-number'))`

Comment: I get undefined @JonathanLam

Comment: I tried with your data and it still work http://jsfiddle.net/9kYES/89/

Comment: Your solution works, with `event.target` I able to get id, but `ui.item.value` show me undefined@GeorgeBailey

Comment: I updated post @TanDuong

Comment: Did you change something in your code? I can also `console.log(ui.item.value)` http://jsfiddle.net/9kYES/92/

Comment: Nope, I not changing anything@TanDuong

Comment: I fixed it. Will make answer now @TanDuong

Comment: That's sound great.

Comment: I posted answer @TanDuong

Answer (score 1):

The `this` event is undefined, because the arrow function does not capture the context (it uses the outside `this` context). If you use the `function(event, ui) { ... }` event handler syntax, then you will get the correct `this`.

Otherwise, you can use `event.target` as an alternative to `this` if you want to get the correct element, as @GeorgeBailey suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems with your code. As you are using `arrow` function as callback on the event handler `this` is not here what you think.

So change this to `event.target`

Secondly, `ui.item.value` , I don't know what is this. But it looks like you are trying to get the value. So use `$(ui).val()` and that should work.

Your final script would look like something below

```js
$('.airport_field_destination').on('autocompleteselect', (event, ui) => {
  var id = Number($(event.target).attr('data-number'))

  $(`#search_legs_${id + 1}_origin_text`).val($(ui).val());
  $(`#search_legs_${id + 1}_origin_id`).val($(ui).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is answer, how to do this

Thank's to @GeorgeBailey suggests for id

I can do it like this `event.target` and use arrow functions or make it like this

```
$('.airport_field_destination').on('autocompleteselect', function(event, ui){
  var id = Number($(this).attr('data-number'))
```

For `ui.item`- `ui` not have `value`

Here is console_log of `ui` - `{item: {…}}item: {type: 1, id: 6540382, fullname: "London (LON), England", name: "London", city: "London", …}__proto__: Object`

So Here is full working code

```
$('.airport_field_destination').on('autocompleteselect', function(event, ui){
  var id = Number($(this).attr('data-number'))
  console.log(ui);
  $(`#search_legs_${id + 1}_origin_text`).val(ui.item.fullname);
  $(`#search_legs_${id + 1}_origin_id`).val(ui.item.id)
});
```