# what does $(element).data('name', this) mean in a customized extend function of jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm learning a custom plugin of jQuery, And see this in the code:

```
$.jqPaginator = function (el, options) {
  if (!(this instanceof $.jqPaginator)) {
    return new $.jqPaginator(el, options)
  }

  var self = this

  self.$container = $(el)

  self.$container.data('jqPaginator', self) ...}
```

And I'm confused why `data()` is not like `$(element).data(name, value)` to set `data-name` to the DOM.

Comment: It's the same. `$container` is a reference to a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an atypical plugin, so if you're studying it for the purposes of understanding plugins in general, look elsewhere.

The [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) call is storing a reference to the `jqPaginator` instance in jQuery's data cache for the element passed in as `el`. That means that later, if given the element, it can get the `jqPaginator` instance for it (if any) by doing this:

```
var instance = $(el).data("jqPaginator");
if (instance) {
    // `instance` is an instance of jqPaginator already attached to the element
    // ...
}
```

Annotated:

```
// Create a variable for functions to close over that refers to
// the current instance of $.jqPaginator
var self = this

// Store a jQuery wrapper for `el` on the instance
self.$container = $(el)

// Store the instance in the jQuery data cache for `el`
self.$container.data('jqPaginator', self) ...}
```

The jQuery data cache is storage linked to the element (but not preventing it from being cleaned up if removed from the DOM) where you can store additional information for the element.

Here's a simple example of `data` at work:

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
    const $btn = $(this);
    const timestamp = $btn.data("timestamp");
    if (!timestamp) {
        console.log("That was the first click of the button, click it again");
        $btn.data("timestamp", new Date());
    } else {
        console.log("That wasn't the first click, the first click was done at " + timestamp.toLocaleTimeString());
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> And I'm confused why `data()` is not like `$(element).data(name, value)` to set `data-name` to the DOM.

`data` never *sets* `data-*` attributes. People sometimes misunderstand the `data` method, thinking it's a simple accessor for `data-*` attributes on the element. It isn't. The first time you use it on an element, it seeds the data cache with any values it finds in `data-*` attribute, but that's all it ever does with them. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219).

Comment: very helpful, Thank you.