# Access Global data-* attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Im trying to write a little filter script for a ajax-table and im trying to open a overlay when someone clicks on the element:

```
<div class="at-filter" data-filter-val="{some_value}" data-filter-type="{some_type}">
...
</div>
```

How do i access the data-filter-type and value via javascript/jquery? Cant find anything at all via google.
Something like this is what im looking for:

```
this.table.find( '.at-filter' ).each(
    function(index, element) {
        var type=$(element).data-filter-type();
        var val=$(element).data-filter-val();
        self.data.filter[type] = {};
        $(element).bind('click', {self:self, val:val, type:type}, type.openContextMenu);
    }
)
```

edit: Mistakes were made!

Comment: @StefanR - That's a good one for doing it with the DOM (which obviously works). I'm having a surprising amount of trouble finding a *good* one using jQuery's API. I can find a lot where `attr` and/or `data` are used but the focus is different. Very surprising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get attrbiute value use jquery [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or in plain JavaScript [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

But

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

Or

In plain JavaScript [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```js
console.log($('.me').attr('data-attribute'));
console.log($('.me').attr('data-second-attr'));

$('.me').each(function() {
  console.log(this.getAttribute('data-attribute'));
  console.log(this.getAttribute('data-second-attr'));
  this.setAttribute('data-second-attr', 'foo-bar');
  console.log('after change', this.getAttribute('data-second-attr'));
})

$('.me').prop('data-attribute', 'baz')
console.log('after change', $('.me').prop('data-attribute'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="me" data-attribute="foo" data-second-attr="bar">yo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
var type = $(element).attr("data-filter-type");
```

You could also use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
var type = $(element).data("filter-type"); // Read the note below, though
```

... but it isn't necessary or really appropriate if all you want to do is access the values of those attributes. Contrary to popular belief, [`data` is **not** an accessor for `data-*` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45149219/157247). (It's both more and less than that.)