# 'this' object is undefined inside callback having parameter, in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I am attaching a callback function to select box on **change** event like this

```
select.on('change', config, party.selectOne);
```

Here **config** is the parameter I am passing to call back function. Inside call back I could access **config** parameter.

But my issue is, inside callback, $(this) returns unexpected object other than select box object

```
party.selectOne= function(config) {
    // is the selectbox
    var selectbox = $(this);
    var api = selectbox.data('api');
}
```

So I am getting **api** as **undefined**. But this will work fine if I don't pass any parameter to call back. What is wrong with me?

Example :

```
<select data-api="{'name':'one','address':'address1'}">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: **Note:** This is **not** a duplicate of [*How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback). The OP is expecting `this` within the callback to be the `select` element.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). With what you have above, `this` within the call to `party.selectOne` should be the `select` on which you've registered the event handler.

Comment: Show your html. Where does `select` come from? show a runnable example code, not just some out-of-context snippets.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/2bujykew/

Answer (score 0):

> So I am getting `api` as undefined.

That means that these two things are true:

1. The element the `change` occurred on (one of the elements in `select` as of your `select.on` call) has never had `.data('api', something)` called on it, and
2. That element doesn't have a `data-api` attribute on it — or rather, it didn't as of the **first** time `.data` was used on it.

**Or**, it could mean that `party.selectOne` has been [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) at some point in code you haven't shown.

(Remember that `data` is **not** an accessor for `data-*` attributes. [It's both more and less than that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219).)

jQuery's set-based nature can trip you up. If you have multiple elements in `select` as of your `select.on` call, and you've only set the `api` data item (directly via `.data`, or indirectly through a `data-api` attribute) on *one* of them, then a `change` event on a *different* one of them may give `undefined` for `.data('api')`. jQuery's data cache is per-element, not per-set.

Answer (score 0):

Not `this` is undefined, but the return value of `data()` for "api" is. 
Use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead of [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```js
// To make this example work
var party = {};
var config = { foo: "bar" };
var select = $("select");
// ---

party.selectOne = function(config) {
    var selectbox = $(this);
    var api = selectbox.attr('data-api');
    
    console.log(api);
    console.log(config.data.foo);
}

select.on('change', config, party.selectOne);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-api="{'name':'one','address':'address1'}">
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved. Here **config** parameter was of type Object. If we pass **config** parameter as string, it will be resolved. I think, if we pass config as **object**, $(this) will refer **config**, instead of referencing **select box** element

Comment: This is not correct. Please refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043823/7575111) where `config` is indeed an object.