# access the value of element within <li> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to access a value of element from document.getElementById() response

already tried

```
$(this).data("data-username")
```

response of `document.getElementById("user-options")` is

```
<li id = "user-options" >
   <a id="header-details-user-fullname" class="aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-dropdown2-trigger-arrowless aui-alignment-target aui-alignment-element-attached-top aui-alignment-element-attached-right aui-alignment-target-attached-bottom aui-alignment-target-attached-right" aria-haspopup="true" data-username="userName123" data-displayname="username" href="/secure/ViewProfile.jspa" title="User profile for user" resolved="" aria-controls="user-options-content" aria-expanded="false">
   <span class="aui-avatar aui-avatar-small">
   <span class="aui-avatar-inner">
   <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3b9c686ef2a52547e0e6dd891f130b1e?d=mm&amp;s=24" alt="User profile for user">
   </span>
   </span>
   </a>
</li>
```

need to access `data-username="userName123"` from the `document.getElementById("user-options")` response

Comment: `$("#user-options [data-username]").data("username")`

Comment: Since your question is not tagged with jQuery, but you did try it with jQuery code. Do you plan to use jQuery?

Comment: $("#user-options [data-username]").data("username") got me the required result thank you user7290573

Comment: @user7290573 - That's the best selector, nice one! For this, though, `data` is probably overkill; [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> need to access data-username="userName123" from the document.getElementById("user-options") response

The data attribute is on the first `a` within that `li`, so:

```
var username = document.getElementById("user-options").querySelector("a").getAttribute("data-username");
```

Or as [user7290573 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849713/access-the-value-of-element-within-li-tag/56849822#comment100249871_56849713), the selector could reference the data attribute:

```
var username = document.getElementById("user-options").querySelector("[data-username]").getAttribute("data-username");
```

You said specifically you wanted to work with the result of `document.getElementById("user-options")`, but you could also do this instead:

```
var username = document.querySelector("#user-options a").getAttribute("data-username");
// or
var username = document.querySelector("#user-options [data-username]").getAttribute("data-username");
```

Live Example (with the `getElementById`):

```js
var username = document.getElementById("user-options").querySelector("[data-username]").getAttribute("data-username");
console.log(username);
```

```html
<li id = "user-options" >
   <a id="header-details-user-fullname" class="aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-dropdown2-trigger-arrowless aui-alignment-target aui-alignment-element-attached-top aui-alignment-element-attached-right aui-alignment-target-attached-bottom aui-alignment-target-attached-right" aria-haspopup="true" data-username="userName123" data-displayname="username" href="/secure/ViewProfile.jspa" title="User profile for user" resolved="" aria-controls="user-options-content" aria-expanded="false">
   <span class="aui-avatar aui-avatar-small">
   <span class="aui-avatar-inner">
   <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3b9c686ef2a52547e0e6dd891f130b1e?d=mm&amp;s=24" alt="User profile for user">
   </span>
   </span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Or if you're using jQuery (your question seems to suggest you might or might not be):

```
var username = $("#user-options a").attr("data-username");
// or
var username = $("#user-options [data-username]").attr("data-username");
```

Live Example:

```js
var username = $("#user-options [data-username]").attr("data-username");
console.log(username);
```

```html
<li id = "user-options" >
   <a id="header-details-user-fullname" class="aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-dropdown2-trigger-arrowless aui-alignment-target aui-alignment-element-attached-top aui-alignment-element-attached-right aui-alignment-target-attached-bottom aui-alignment-target-attached-right" aria-haspopup="true" data-username="userName123" data-displayname="username" href="/secure/ViewProfile.jspa" title="User profile for user" resolved="" aria-controls="user-options-content" aria-expanded="false">
   <span class="aui-avatar aui-avatar-small">
   <span class="aui-avatar-inner">
   <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3b9c686ef2a52547e0e6dd891f130b1e?d=mm&amp;s=24" alt="User profile for user">
   </span>
   </span>
   </a>
</li>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You'll get people saying to use `data` here, but if you're just trying to get the value, `data` is overkill. (`data` is **not** just an accessor for `data-*` attributes, it's [both more and less than that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219).) Still, just for completeness, it would be: `var username = $("#user-options a").data("username");`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *data* part from the parameter as `data()` is already doing that. Try

```
$('#user-options a').data('username')
```

```js
console.log($('#user-options a').data('username'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id = "user-options" >
  <a id="header-details-user-fullname" class="aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-dropdown2-trigger-arrowless aui-alignment-target aui-alignment-element-attached-top aui-alignment-element-attached-right aui-alignment-target-attached-bottom aui-alignment-target-attached-right" aria-haspopup="true" data-username="userName123" data-displayname="username" href="/secure/ViewProfile.jspa" title="User profile for user" resolved="" aria-controls="user-options-content" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="aui-avatar aui-avatar-small">
    <span class="aui-avatar-inner">
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3b9c686ef2a52547e0e6dd891f130b1e?d=mm&amp;s=24" alt="User profile for user">
      </span>
  </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Although the OP tried using `this`, there's no indication that `this` in their code is referencing the `a` element. Indeed, there's some suggestion that it isn't (since they mention uses `getElementById`).

Comment: Ah, you slipped a ninja edit in as I was pressing Enter on the above. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `document.querySelector` and `getAttribute`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#user-options a').getAttribute("data-username"))
```

```html
<li id = "user-options" >
<a id="header-details-user-fullname" class="aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-dropdown2-trigger-arrowless aui-alignment-target aui-alignment-element-attached-top aui-alignment-element-attached-right aui-alignment-target-attached-bottom aui-alignment-target-attached-right" aria-haspopup="true" data-username="userName123" data-displayname="username" href="/secure/ViewProfile.jspa" title="User profile for user" resolved="" aria-controls="user-options-content" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="aui-avatar aui-avatar-small">
                <span class="aui-avatar-inner">
                    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3b9c686ef2a52547e0e6dd891f130b1e?d=mm&amp;s=24" alt="User profile for user">
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
</li>
```