# jQuery if data attribute add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new to JS and jQuery, but I try adding a class "hide" to an element if it has a data attribute 
with a specific string. So if "class" hat a data-rating attribute of "0.0", the class "hide" should be added. It doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         if ($(".class").data('rating') === ('0.0')){
         $(".class").addClass('hide');
        }
      });
```

Comment: Could you show the HTML of the `.class` element. It's likely that the value has been converted to an int or float. You may also need a loop if there are multiple elements with that class

Comment: (Why do people do stuff like `('0.0')` to begin with? Do they really think text literals would “feel naked” or “freeze to death”, if they don’t blanket them in braces …?)

Comment: @CBroe like I said I'm new to JS and jQuery, I just found this line so I used it as it is.
you mean the line in the html where that class is used? 
<span class="class" id="someID" data-rating="0.0">

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery .data() does not work, but .attr() does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does)

Comment: It works perfectly. what the problem occuring?

Comment: Important takeaway from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45149219/215552): "This is the result of a misunderstanding: **`data` is NOT an accessor for `data-*` attributes. It's both more and less than that**."

Answer (score 1):

jQuery recognises `data-rating="0.0"` as numeric, so when you call `$(".class").data('rating')` you get the *number* `0`. Hence, strictly comparing it to any string will fail.

Additionally, your code will not behave as expected if there is more than one element with the given class.

```
$(".class").each(elem=>{
    const $elem = $(elem);
    if( $elem.data('rating') === 0) {
        $elem.addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Or, without jQuery (and therefore immeasurably faster)...

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class").forEach(elem=>{
    if( parseFloat(elem.getAttribute("data-rating")) === 0) {
        elem.classList.add("hide");
    }
});
```

---

Rapid shift back to jQuery, you could also do this:

```
$(".class[data-rating='0.0']").addClass('hide');
```

... as a one-liner.