# How to increment data index in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried to update `data` attribute as my work below.

When I click square,`data` attribute should be `incremented`.

But the result is a little bit different. It seems not to be incremented.

How can I fix them?

And Why this issue inccured?

Thanks

```js
$("td").click(function() {
  index=$(this).data('layer');
  index+=1
  $(this).attr('data-layer',index);
  console.log(this);
});
```

```css
td {
border:solid black 1px;
width:50px;
height:50px;
cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-layer="0"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: because you data layer is always  0  and when you click the button it always starts from 1 and you are attaching your event listener to the first td only not to the previous one as you are expecting which would give you a sequence

Comment: there's a semicolon missing at `index+=1`

Comment: `data()` is not just a getter for `data-` attributes. See [jQuery .data() does not work, but .attr() does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8707226/215552)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Html element can have a [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) and/or an [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes).

In your code you get the value of the dataset and change like if it is an attribute. This is your mistake.

For more details see [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

If you are inrested in attribues you need to use:

```js
$("td").click(function() {
    index=$(this).attr('data-layer');
    index = index + 1;
    $(this).attr('data-layer',index);
    console.log(this);
});
```

Instead, if you need to use dataset:

```js
$("td").click(function() {
    index=$(this).data('layer');
    index = index + 1;
    $(this).data('layer',index);
    console.log($(this).data('layer'));
});
```

```css
td {
      border:solid black 1px;
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
      cursor:pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-layer="0"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("td").click(function() {
  const index = $(this).attr('data-layer');
  const newIndex = Number(index) + 1;
  $(this).attr('data-layer', newIndex);
  console.log(this);
});
```

```css
td {
border:solid black 1px;
width:50px;
height:50px;
cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-layer="0"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @dgknca it's a string

Comment: @dgknca try it yourself and see if it's a number or not

Comment: you can see with typeof index