# data-id not updated on click event

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I'm new to jQuery. I have link with a `data-id` attribute which is dynamically updated from select option value

```
<a id="jabatanID" href="#" data-id="{{$jabatan_id}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block assigndata">Click</a>
```

The idea is if `data-id` is empty, then fire `swal.alert`, and then if not empty show modal and pass the `data-id` value to input id

The click button event are work for the first attempt, the problem is when i change the option select value this event `$(".modal-body #jabatan_id").val(jabatan_id);` not update with the new data-id value, even though `data-id="{{$jabatan_id}}"` was updated with new value

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".assigndata").click(function () {
            var jabatan_id = $(this).data('id');
            if(jabatan_id == ''){
                Swal.fire({title: "Warning", text: "Please Choose jabatan ID", icon:"warning"});
            }
            else {
                $('#attachsertifikat').modal('show');
                $(".modal-body #jabatan_id").val(jabatan_id);
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there any cache on data-id that i have to reset or something??

Update with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5b3ohgj/)

Comment: What do you mean by `when i change the option select...` ? Also are that button dynamically generated ? is your button event get called ?

Comment: Please check my example at given jsfiddle above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the data-id value with

```js
    var jabatan_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

This is because you are setting the value with .attr('data-id') when changing the select value. Basically you should either use .data() or .attr() and not mix the two. You can find a more elaborate explanation on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708345/9663971).