# Pass the parameter in jquery function as in javascript onclick

Tags: jquery

How to get the id in jquery "on" function as in javascript onclick function ?
thanks in advance

html

```
@foreach ($datas as $key=>$data)
    <Button onclick="viewReturn('{{$data->id}}')" class="get-data">Save</Button>
@endforeach
```

javascript

```
function viewReturn(id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'Get',
        url: basePath + "getData/" + id,
    })
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).on('click', 'get-data', function(){
    //how to get $data->id here?
})
```

Comment: Your selector `'get-data'` implies that you have a `<get-data>` element. A class selector would look like `".get-data"`. Consider using a `data-*` attribute like `data-id="{{$data->id}}"` and getting `$(this).data("id")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the code at the top to using a delegated jQuery event handler, you need to:

1. Put the `id` value in a `data-*` attribute
2. Add a `.` on `".get-data"` so it's a class selector, not a tag selector
3. Get the `data-*` attribute from the element

#1 looks like this:

```
@foreach ($datas as $key=>$data)
    <Button data-id="{{$data->id}}" class="get-data">Save</Button>
@endforeach
```

#2 and #3 look like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".get-data", function(){
    const id = this.getAttribute("data-id");
    // ...use `id`...
});
```

or on any even *vaguely* modern browser (we're talking IE11+), you can use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) rather than `getAttribute`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".get-data", function(){
    const id = this.dataset.id;
    // ...use `id`...
});
```

---

Side note: You will have people telling you to use the jQuery `data` function. There's no reason to do that in what you've posted (though it would work). `data` is **not** just an accessor for `data-*` attributes, [it's both more and less than that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219).