# jQuery not return updated data-value

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. click on first `green` button
2. click check price button, return right? okay
3. click second green button, then click again check price, return wrong! why?

```js
$('button.setprice').click(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  $('.price').text(txt).attr('data-price', txt);
});

$('.check').on('click',function(){
  alert($('.price').data('price'))
});
```

```css
.setprice {
background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price"></div>

<button class="setprice">1000</button>
<button class="setprice">2000</button>
<br/>
<button class="check">check price</button>
```

Comment: Try with `$('.price').attr('data-price')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery .data() does not work, but .attr() does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/8708345#8708345)

Comment: `attr()` reads from the DOM, `data()` reads from a cache in memory which jQuery holds. You need to use the ***same method as getter and setter***. You cannot mix and match.

Comment: Thanks everyone, now I understand what was my problem, regard

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can't mix `data()` and `attr()` functions. It is well explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708345/3785618

> Since `.data()` does extra processing jQuery stores the results of attribute evaluation in `$.cache` - after all, once a data attribute has been evaluated it would be wasteful to re-evaluate on every `.data()` call - especially since data variables can contain complex JSON strings.

Although, this will work:

```js
$('button.setprice').click(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  $('.price').text(txt).data('price', txt);
});

$('.check').on('click',function(){
  alert($('.price').data('price'))
});
```

```css
.setprice {
background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price"></div>

<button class="setprice">1000</button>
<button class="setprice">2000</button>
<br/>
<button class="check">check price</button>
```