# How to get data attribute from a DIV and write it to another DIV using jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to get a data attribute value from a clicked DIV and pass it as data attr for a displaying new DIV:

DIVs to select by click:

```
<div class="mySlot" data-slot-label="a">A</div>
<div class="mySlot" data-slot-label="b">B</div>
<div class="mySlot" data-slot-label="c">C</div>
```

The popup DIV that carries over the data-slot value on its as its attr:

```
<div class="selection" data-slot-label="[The Selected DIV data]"></div>
```

I'm using this now, but not working:

```
$('.mySlot').click(function() {
    var mydata = $('.mySlot').data('slot-label');
    $('.selection').data('slot-label',mydata);
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.mySlot').click(function() {
    var mydata = $(this).attr('data-slot-label');
    $('.selection').attr('data-slot-label',mydata);
});
```

Just use the [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to add or retrive the data from an element

Comment: This topic is already well-covered by [previous questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219), no need for more of them. *(edit: not my downvote)*